# Should I put this function in View (code-behind) or in ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am creating a simple WPF Application. I've a function OpenFile:

```
private void OpenFile(string fileName)
{
   if(!File.Exists(Helper.GetPath(fileName)))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error opening file");
   }
   else
   {
      //Code to handle file opening
   }
}
```

Ideally where should this function be present? I feel it should be in `.xaml.cs` because it accesses a MessageBox which comes in the `View` part. But it also calls my Helper, which is in the model. So I also think it can be in the `ViewModel`. What is the advantage of having this in the `View` or in the `ViewModel`? Can someone help me with some pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the advantages of placing it in the view model would be testability. You could write a unit test that checks that the message box is only displayed if the file exists for example (more accurately it would be an integration test if you are hitting the file system).

However, because you are using a message box directly, your test would never complete on a build server because the machine would be waiting for input from the user whilst the message box is displayed.

Therefore, I would work against an abstraction in your view model, so that you can [mock the message box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225703/how-to-prevent-wpf-enums-in-modelview) during tests.

Answer (score 7):

This function must be in the ViewModel. You need to create an operation in your view for showing the error message and call this method instead of `MessageBox.Show`. Showing the message box needs to be done in the `View`.

Generally you should avoid implementing any business logic inside the `View` such as validating or handling a file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Microsoft Prism you can use the [`IInteractionRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.interactivity.interactionrequest.iinteractionrequest(v=pandp.38).aspx) interface to have the view create the `MessageBox`, but actually pass back the necessary response to the view-model.

If you are **not** using Microsoft Prism, then look at how this part works and either simulate it or use a framework that does something similar.

---

Basically, that code should go on your view-model for testability, but replace the line where you explicitly call the MessageBox and use the `IInteractionRequest` mentioned instead.

Here is the documentation pertinent to the scenario you're looking to implement: [Chapter 6: Advanced MVVM Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405494(v=pandp.40).aspx). Look at the section stated *User Interaction Patterns*.